# Can I programmatically add a qualifier to a bean?

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I am registering transaction managers in my code, I would normally use annotation based configuration but as I don't know until runtime how many data sources (and hence transaction managers) there will be, I have to programmatically register these, as follows:

```
private final void registerTransactionManagerBean(final DataSource dataSource, ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {

    String transactionManagerName = this.getName() + "-transactionManager";

    context.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton(transactionManagerName, new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource));

    LOG.info("Registering transaction manager under name : " + transactionManagerName);
}
```

Assuming this.getName() returned 'mydb', I originally expected to be able to qualify a transaction manager like this:

```
@Transactional("mydb-transactionManager")
```

What I've realised however is the value of that annotation refers to the qualifier and not the name. I did a quick test by declaring a bean as below and it works:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("mydb-transactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager test() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().build());
}
```

My question is, is there a way I can programmatically add a qualifier when registering a bean?

## UPDATE

I've worked this out, I'm falling foul of this problem (in BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils:isQualifierMatch):

```
catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException ex) {
// ignore - can't compare qualifiers for a manually registered singleton object
}
```

I am manually registering my transaction manager bean so I presume this is why I'm stuck. I'm not really sure what options that gives me apart from to not programmatically register transaction managers as a runtime thing sadly.

Comment: Just programmatically register the bean with the name you want.

Comment: I do:    context.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton(transactionManagerName, new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource)); The issue is that it is not the name specifically I need to register, it is the qualifier.

Comment: Why do you need to register the qualifier? Can't you obtain the programmatically registered bean with it's name?

Comment: I want to use the annotation @Transactional. If you have more than one transaction manager, you need to reference them by qualifier name - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#tx-multiple-tx-mgrs-with-attransactional

Comment: And using the bean name as the qualifier value doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't. The bean name and the qualifier are two distinct things as I understand it.

Comment: There is a method called 'addQualifier' on AbstractBeanDefinition which I believe is the one I want to use

Comment: I am sure that the name and the qualifier are two different things, but I have no proof of either. Interesting point!

Comment: qualifier and name are, in theory, different things. However when no qualifier is found it will lookup a bean by its name. This is also mentioned in the [javadocs of @Transactional](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#value--). Basically it should work.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I'm 99% sure this isn't actually the case, at least in Spring 3.9. I looked at the code in BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils (qualifiedBeanOfType) and my transactionManager is one of teh candidate beans, but fails the isQualifierMatch test.

Comment: How do you intend to annotate your @Transactional methods if you don't know which tx manager to use until runtime? What are you trying to achieve through dynamic tx manager registration?

Comment: Hi Jukka. By 'runtime' I mean a YAML configuration file that is passed to the application. This might be a hard one to explain here but we are combining Dropwizard and Spring, and was hoping our framework could do all the dynamic registration based on reading of the YAML configuration files. I can configure everything programatically, but these are manually registered singleton objects, which Spring can't compare qualifiers for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked this out, I'm falling foul of this problem:

```
catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException ex) {
// ignore - can't compare qualifiers for a manually registered singleton object
}
```

I am manually registering my transaction manager bean so I presume this is why I'm stuck. I'm not really sure what options that gives me apart from to not programatically register transaction managers as a runtime thing sadly.

Raised as a JIRA issue - https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11915

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RuntimeRegistrationWithQualifierTest {
    private AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;

    @Test
    public void beanWithQualifier() {

        final GenericBeanDefinition helloBeanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
        helloBeanDefinition.addQualifier(new AutowireCandidateQualifier(Hello.class));

        final GenericBeanDefinition worldBeanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
        worldBeanDefinition.addQualifier(new AutowireCandidateQualifier(World.class));

        final DefaultListableBeanFactory factory = context.getDefaultListableBeanFactory();

        factory.registerBeanDefinition("helloBean", helloBeanDefinition);
        factory.registerSingleton("helloBean", "hello");

        factory.registerBeanDefinition("worldBean", worldBeanDefinition);
        factory.registerSingleton("worldBean", "world");

        context.register(Foo.class);

        context.refresh();

        final Foo foo = context.getBean(Foo.class);

        assertThat(foo.hello).isEqualTo("hello");
        assertThat(foo.world).isEqualTo("world");
    }

    @Before
    public void newContext() {
        context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    }

    @Qualifier
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Target({FIELD, PARAMETER})
    @interface Hello {}

    @Qualifier
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Target({FIELD, PARAMETER})
    @interface World {}

    static class Foo {
        final String hello;
        final String world;

        Foo(@Hello final String hello, @World final String world) {
            this.hello = hello;
            this.world = world;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to create bean with a qualifier programatically, but with the regular `@Qualifier`, not custom interface. 
In such a case, one have to use 2 arg constructoor of the 
AutowireCandidateQualifier, like: `worldBeanDefinition.addQualifier(new AutowireCandidateQualifier(Qualifier.class, "nameLikeInNormalQualifier"))`